# How to create a Golf Stableford Calculator in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I've been given the task of making a Golf Stableford calculator program in Python that will read a text file from sys.stdin and output the Handicap score of each golfer in the text file. In the text file the first line is the par for each hole on all 18 holes, the second line had the index(difficulty ranking) of each hole. Then every line following that has the name of the golfer, the handicap strokes for the golfer and the strokes they had on each hole from 1-18. If the golfer has an "X" score then that hole is ignored. If it has anything else then the golfer is disqualified.

Here is the given text file:

```
4 5 3 4 4 5 3 5 3 5 3 4 4 4 4 5 4 3
16 4 8 2 18 14 10 6 12 11 15 5 13 1 17 7 3 9
Raspberry Pie 14 4 7 3 5 10 7 4 12 4 5 3 4 4 5 5 5 4 4
Penelope Perkins 17 4 7 3 5 10 7 4 12 4 5 3 4 4 5 5 5 4 4
Bambi 19 5 6 4 5 5 6 4 6 ; 6 4 5 5 5 5 6 5 4
Sylvester The Cat 36 X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X
Sneezy 18 5 6 4 5 5 6 4 6 4 6 4 5 5 5 5 6 5 4
Juninho 18 5 6 4 5 5 6 4 6 4 A 4 5 5 5 5 6 5 4
Shere Khan 7 4 X 3 4 4 5 1 4 3 5 3 X 4 4 4 5 4 3
Alexis de Sart 0 4 3 1 X 2 5 3 4 1 5 3 3 3 3 3 5 4 3
```

Here is the desired output:

```
$ python3 stableford.py < golf.txt
   Alexis de Sart : 47
       Shere Khan : 40
 Penelope Perkins : 38
           Sneezy : 36
    Raspberry Pie : 35
Sylvester The Cat :  0
            Bambi : Disqualified
          Juninho : Disqualified
```

I think I have figured out how to calculate the handicap score for each golfer. You find the difference between the strokes the golfer had on each hole and the strokes needed to par the hole, find the number of handicap points that difference is worth(e.g difference of +2=0, +1=1, 0=2, -1=3 etc.) and add that to the handicap strokes at the start of each line. I also know that I can disqualify the two golfers by using exception handling.

What I have a problem figuring out how to assign the name to the value. I understand that I can assign a key to a value with dictionaries, but I'm not sure how to get the the full names using regular expressions without getting the other letters brought up in the text file.

This is the code I used to get to that stage:

```
import sys
import re
par=sys.stdin.readline().split()
Index=sys.stdin.readline().split()
everything="".join(sys.stdin.readlines())
name=r"([A-Za-z][A-Za-z]*)"
name_regex = re.compile(name)
namelist = name_regex.findall(everything)
for n in namelist:
        print(n)
```

I've spent the past few hours googling information from past questions on here to online guides on python that may help me finish this program but it's gotten me nowhere. I understand that this is a fairly big task so if there is anyway that some of you could potentially help me the I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Unfortunately this type of question is too broad for this platform. You're only supposed to post highly focussed/specialised problem descriptions.

Comment: Where else would you recommend posting this?

Comment: A service like this, possibly: https://hackhands.com/

Comment: Marc simply gave too much information when his question was how to parse the golfer lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `str.rsplit` with the `maxsplit` argument?

```
import io

s = """Raspberry Pie 14 4 7 3 5 10 7 4 12 4 5 3 4 4 5 5 5 4 4
Penelope Perkins 17 4 7 3 5 10 7 4 12 4 5 3 4 4 5 5 5 4 4
Bambi 19 5 6 4 5 5 6 4 6 ; 6 4 5 5 5 5 6 5 4
Sylvester The Cat 36 X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X
Sneezy 18 5 6 4 5 5 6 4 6 4 6 4 5 5 5 5 6 5 4
Juninho 18 5 6 4 5 5 6 4 6 4 A 4 5 5 5 5 6 5 4
Shere Khan 7 4 X 3 4 4 5 1 4 3 5 3 X 4 4 4 5 4 3
Alexis de Sart 0 4 3 1 X 2 5 3 4 1 5 3 3 3 3 3 5 4 3"""

file = io.StringIO(s)
for line in file:
    name, handicap, *scores = line.rstrip().rsplit(maxsplit=19)
    print('{} | {} | {}'.format(name, handicap, scores))

# Output
# Raspberry Pie | 14 | ['4', '7', '3', '5', '10', '7', '4', '12', '4', '5', '3', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '4', '4']
# Penelope Perkins | 17 | ['4', '7', '3', '5', '10', '7', '4', '12', '4', '5', '3', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '4', '4']
# Bambi | 19 | ['5', '6', '4', '5', '5', '6', '4', '6', ';', '6', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '5', '4']
# Sylvester The Cat | 36 | ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
# Sneezy | 18 | ['5', '6', '4', '5', '5', '6', '4', '6', '4', '6', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '5', '4']
# Juninho | 18 | ['5', '6', '4', '5', '5', '6', '4', '6', '4', 'A', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '5', '4']
# Shere Khan | 7 | ['4', 'X', '3', '4', '4', '5', '1', '4', '3', '5', '3', 'X', '4', '4', '4', '5', '4', '3']
# Alexis de Sart | 0 | ['4', '3', '1', 'X', '2', '5', '3', '4', '1', '5', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '5', '4', '3']
```

Comment: That worked. I actually made a slight change where instead of saying s="Raspberry.....", I made s="".join(sys.stdin.readlines) so when the program was executed it world actually open the golf.txt file and I got the same output as yourself. Thanks man.

Comment: you can change the loop to `for line in sys.stdin:`. It will automatically grab each line from stdin for you. The `io.StringIO` class is just for treating a string like a file.

Comment: or if you have a golf.txt file.... `with open('golf.txt') as f: for line in f: ...`

Answer (score 0):

In golf, each hole on a regulation course is ranked based on difficulty, which you have in your data set.  However, when computing a golfer's net score for a given hole you have to account for the handicap for the course.  For example, if the golf is a 10 handicap then he/she only gets handicap strokes for the 10 most difficult holes.

Here is are a couple of examples
Golfer's handicap: 10
Hole #4, Difficulty 4, Golfer's gross score: 8, Golfer's net score: 7
Hole #7, Difficulty 12, Golfer's gross score: 6, Golfer's net score: 6 (net and gross are the same in this case because golfer's handicap is 10 and hole difficulty is 12)

Comment: What's the difference between the gross score and the net score?

Comment: Per hole, the gross score is the number of shots the golfer took for the hole.  The net score on a hole, is the gross score minus the number of handicap stokes the golfer has.  Handicap strokes are based on the hole difficulty and  the golfer's handicap.